# text-to-SQL LLM that queries multiple data sources/databases,

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, large-language-model, fine-tuning

I want to finetune an LLM to the text to sql generation, and I want to execute that sql on multiple databases
example: “**I want to know the total number of students in LA**”, and I specify *database1*, and *database2*
*database1* has 300 student , and *database2* has 200
the response should be “**500 students**”, the issues here is that the column names and the table names could be different (Student_name and Namestudent)
what's the correct approach to do so?

now I only have a langchain sql agent that uses openai to generate the SQL and it can only query one database